# How do I get id3 tags working in Rhythmbox on 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, rhythmbox, id3

I've been using Rhythmbox to gradually back up my CD collection to FLAC files. On Ubuntu 17.04 and earlier, I'd insert the CD, add any metadata that Music Brainz didn't find for me, and hit extract.
The FLAC files created would be tagged with metadata such as track, artist, album, genre, etc.

I've just upgraded to 17.10 and tried to continue with business as usual. However, none of these tags are being written to the files any more. The only tag that gets written is Title, and instead of the track title, the file name is appearing there.

Is there some library that got removed on the upgrade that I need to reinstall? What has changed?

Comment: Curious: the tags display correctly as the track is being recorded, and then disappear as the recording completes and the file is finalized/saved.